# Mocking (in java) with object tree / net

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

Theoretical scenario: 
We have an interface implemented using spring batch, which when triggered fetches a complicated object tree from a service. The type of service is not relevant, it is a pojo and return normal objects. It is transformed into our domain model and then using certain business logic calculations are performed. The data is sent on to the next system using another service.

So I want to test the transformation and business logic mentioned above and have quite a few test cases that already exist in dbs (behind the first services). This is a typical case for mocking. I can mock the incoming and outgoing services using one of the many mocking frameworks out there (mockito etc.). What I am wondering about is are best practices for this scenario: how can I capture the results of service calls (i.e. the result in the form of vanilla objects) and store them in serialised, marshalled form, which I can then use behind a mock?

This has to be a quite common scenario? I have found a few bits and pieces, things like XMLEncode, Xstream, simple etc. on the serialisation side of things and various test frameworks like fitnesse etc. that don't quite fit the bill. I've looked at and used mocking frameworks in the past, but I haven't found anything yet that brings both of these topics together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your use case for serializing the arguments of your service. With Mockito you can very easily provide an input from your first service, capture the results sent to the second service and make assertions upon the model in Java.

See [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

Comment: Imagine the following code: `Mockito.when(wholesaleService.getWholesaleLoans(1024234)).thenReturn(bigDeepListOfWholesaleloans);`  and imagine bigDeepListOfWholesaleloans is a deep and wide object graph. I am looking for some way to save the tedious job of constructing this large list in source code. I would have thought than this would be a common problem for all but the most trivial of unit tests.

Comment: Thanks @dashambles, for me the serialisation, mocking and parameterised testing are all orthogonal problems that don't conflict with each other. You've mentioned XStream already which has a very simple API. I would also recommend [JUnitParamsRunner](https://code.google.com/p/junitparams/) as simple parameterised testing tool. Once you have your test data persisted in xml, You can create a few utility methods to load them easily for Mockito and have the file name as a parameter in the test.